# Users scrolling down a page: how do I count averages between reading times?

Tags: mysql

I try to find out how long people read each section of a page. I've saved this kind of data to MySQL and now try to analyze it.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
- section  ---  load time            ---  id                    -
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-  1       ---  2015-04-24 12:23:33  ---  101                   -
-  2       ---  2015-04-24 12:25:00  ---  101                   -
-  1       ---  2015-04-24 12:33:00  ---  102                   -
-  2       ---  2015-04-24 12:34:00  ---  102                   -
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

What kind of SQL query would count the average time difference (in seconds) between sections 1 and 2? I tried several queries but got only error messages.

Comment: What kind of queries did you try, and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(load time))  as seconds FROM tablename WHERE section = 1) as secondsSection1, 
    (SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(load time))  as seconds FROM tablename WHERE section = 1) as secondsSection2,
    secondsSection2 -  secondsSection1  as seconds_difference,
    seconds_difference / 2 as avarage_seconds
FROM
    tablename
```

Now I hard coded "tablename" and "2" in the code.
You could also use an inner select to count the amount of records there are.

Basically what I would do is count all the time stamp in seconds, and subtract the section 1 seconds from the section 2 seconds. (So you have a difference)

Device this between the amount of compared records and you will have an average.